# setInterval doesn't work on right mouse click (IE9)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, setinterval

Why does `setInterval` stop when the right mouse button is clicked and the menu appears, and does not continue until the menu disappears? And how can I work around?

I try to program a simple timer, but as described above, the timer stops as soon as the right mouse is clicked and the menu appears, and does not work until the menu disappears.

Comment: I have a feeling this is something that cannot be fixed as its default IE behavior (read broken behavior)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I found, however, a simple solution for my timer: I do not count down, but take the difference of two timestamps and subtract it from the initial amount of seconds. I hope this helps if sombody else experiences the same problem.

Comment: +Simon, if you have the solution, why don't you post an answer below?!

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround** You can prevent the context menu from appearing by stopping the contextmenu event.

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```